# How to load a MEF component from another assembly in .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, mef

I'm just taking my first baby steps in the MEF territory and wanted to do so using .net core 2.1.

Using VS 2017 (version 15.8.8) I've done a small Console App (.NET Core) with an interface

```
interface IMessageSender
{
    void Send(string message);
}
```

and an implementation (in the same project)

```
[Export(typeof(IMessageSender))]
public class EmailSender : IMessageSender
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EmailSender : " + message);
    }
}
```

Finally I have a small compose method executed from my Main(string[] args)

```
    [Import]
    private void Compose()
    {
        var assembly_A = new[] { typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly };
        var config_A = new ContainerConfiguration().WithAssembly(assembly_A[0]);
        var container_A = config_A.CreateContainer();
        var msg_A = container_A.GetExport<IMessageSender>();
        msg_A.Send("Hello");
    }
```

It works as expected

[image]

However, if I add a new class library to my solution and move my implementation of Send(string) to the newly added project things do not work out.

```
namespace AnotherMefExtensionProjectNamespace
{
  [Export(typeof(IMessageSender))]
  public class EmailSenderExtended : IMessageSender
  {
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EmailSenderExtended : " + message);
    }
  }
}
```

The new Compose method

```
    [Import]
    public IMessageSender MessageSender { get; set; }
    private void Compose()
    {
        var assembly_B = new[] { typeof(EmailSenderExtended).GetTypeInfo().Assembly };
        var config_B = new ContainerConfiguration().WithAssembly(assembly_B[0]);
        var container_B = config_B.CreateContainer();
        var msg_B = container_B.GetExport<IMessageSender>();
        msg_B.Send("Hello");
    }
```

[image]

I've tried to compare the different configs and containers (_A versus _B in the examples) but can't understand what is different. I've even tried to extend the class ContainerConfiguration to load from a specified assembly and it works as long as the given file contains the Main method but fails if I use my "extended" .NET Core Class Library.

```
        public static ContainerConfiguration WithChosenAssembly(this ContainerConfiguration configuration, string pathAndFile)
    {
        var context = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(pathAndFile);
        var ass_list = new List<Assembly>() { context };
        configuration = configuration.WithAssemblies(ass_list, null);
        return configuration;
    }
```

I was under the impression that you extend your main application by developing a class library that basically implements the interfaces specified. 
I seem to be unable to do this currently, but obviously I misunderstood something very basic.

If someone would care to put me on the right track or give me an alternative idea for "plug-in" development for .net core I would be very grateful.

King regards
Magnus

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my test setup does not mimic any real world scenario and thus I brought my problems on myself.

Obviously I should have had three projects.

1. One project with only the interface definitions.
2. One "main" project where all my regular code exists.
3. One (or more) projects where my MEF implementations of the interfaces exist.

Reviewing my example and adhering to the obvious "design" above it all works exactly as it should. 
Most StackOverflow users probably wouldn't make my blunder but for those that did, I hope the above helps.  :-)